# conflict between Native JS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was going through a text book and got caught up with a problem in an example.

Here's my html:

```js
$(function(){
 $("#checkAll").click(function(){
  $("[name=items]:checkbox").attr("checked", true);
  console.log("check all");
 });
 $("#checkNo").click(function(){
  $("[name=items]:checkbox").attr("checked", false);
  console.log("check none");
 });
 $("#checkRev").click(function(){
  $("[name=items]:checkbox").each(function(){
   this.checked = !(this.checked);
  });
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>practice</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practice.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <label for="items">你最喜欢的运动是：</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="羽毛球">羽毛球
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="篮球">篮球
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="足球">足球
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="乒乓球">乒乓球
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="checkAll" value="Check All">
  <input type="button" id="checkNo" value="Check None">
  <input type="button" id="checkRev" value="Reversed Check">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="practice.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you click the "reversed check" button first, the "check all" and "check none" buttons won't work when you click them. Then I changed the codes under the click Event of button "reversed checked" to jQuery functions. Here's the revised js codes:

```js
$(function(){
 $("#checkAll").click(function(){
  $("[name=items]:checkbox").attr("checked", true);
  console.log("check all");
 });
 $("#checkNo").click(function(){
  $("[name=items]:checkbox").attr("checked", false);
  console.log("check none");
 });
 $("#checkRev").click(function(){
  $("[name=items]:checkbox").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("checked", !($(this).attr("checked"))); //here's the changed part!!!
  });
 });
})
```

In this case, if you manually check any checkbox, any of the three buttons won't work on that specific checkbox.

I suspect there's might be a subtle conflict between native HTML-JS attributes and jQuery functions.

I'd really appreciate some of you guys telling me the mechanism that leads to this malfunction. Thanks!

Comment: You must not place a `<script>` element before the doctype.

Comment: Remove the jquery you're calling from CDN.. you're already importing a newer version from your project.. besides.. as @Bergi said before, don't call anything before the doctype...

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the *attribute*, set the *property*. (Which is what `this.checked = ...` is doing.) That is, use jQuery's  `.prop()` method not `.attr()`.

```js
$(function(){
 $("#checkAll").click(function(){
  $("[name=items]:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
  console.log("check all");
 });
 $("#checkNo").click(function(){
  $("[name=items]:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
  console.log("check none");
 });
 $("#checkRev").click(function(){
  $("[name=items]:checkbox").each(function(){
   this.checked = !(this.checked);
  });
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>practice</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practice.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <label for="items">你最喜欢的运动是：</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="羽毛球">羽毛球
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="篮球">篮球
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="足球">足球
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="乒乓球">乒乓球
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="checkAll" value="Check All">
  <input type="button" id="checkNo" value="Check None">
  <input type="button" id="checkRev" value="Reversed Check">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="practice.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```js
$(function(){
 $("#checkAll").click(function(){
  $("input[name=items]").prop("checked", true);
  console.log("check all");
 });
 $("#checkNo").click(function(){
  $("input[name=items]").prop("checked", false);
  console.log("check none");
 });
 $("#checkRev").click(function(){
  $("input[name=items]").each(function(){
   this.checked = !(this.checked);
  });
 });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>practice</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practice.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <label for="items">你最喜欢的运动是：</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="羽毛球">羽毛球
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="篮球">篮球
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="足球">足球
  <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="乒乓球">乒乓球
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="checkAll" value="Check All">
  <input type="button" id="checkNo" value="Check None">
  <input type="button" id="checkRev" value="Reversed Check">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="practice.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```